# Getting extra spaces in CodeIgniter MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

The code for the query I'm trying to run is

```
$query = $this->db->select("*")->from('items')->like("replace(name, '=', ' ')", "foo bar", 'both')->get();

$items = $query->num_rows();
```

Mysql query string is

```
SELECT replace(name, ' = ', ' ') FROM `items`
```

What the code is doing is adding a blank space before and after "=" when compiling the query resulting in " = " which returns no results as there are no items with " = " in their names, only "=".

```
foo=bar, replace(name, '=', ' ') returns 1 result.
foo = bar, replace(name, ' = ', ' ') returns 0 results.
```

The version of CodeIgniter that I'm using is: 3.0.6

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do this in mysql? Its not a great approach. You would maybe want to do a str replace on the string before/after you do a query to the db.

Comment: @Philip The reason I'm doing this is that what I'm looking to replace is not always the same thing, it works perfect with ".", "-" or "+" together but with "=" the problem happens.

Comment: give me an example so I can offer a solution.

Comment: $query = $this->db->select("*")->from('items')->like("replace(replace(replace(name, '=', ' '), '.', ' '), '-', ' ')", "foo bar", 'both')->get();

And you have this items on your table

foo = bar, foo . bar, foo - bar

Comment: I understand the query you are trying to run. I am just not sure **WHY** you are doing it that way. It does not make any sense. It would make more sense to just query the db with your like filter, then iterate over each element and replace the string

Comment: @Philip I get that, but when filtering the results it will throw nothing, which is the point of doing the replacements is that the names are replaced before filtering the results, that way I can guarantee that the names are standardized before even doing the filter so that results are shown. for example "foo = bar" will be "foo bar" and searching foo bar will return some results.

Comment: Why are you doing this is what I am asking? FOO should be a mysql KEY and BAR the value.

Comment: @Philip foo = bar is the whole field, that's why sometimes it can be foo = bar, foo . bar or foo + bar. its not "foo" = "bar" it is "foo = bar".

Comment: Yes but that kind of string manipulation can be done before it gets sent for final render, just like xss.

Comment: @Philip please refer to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32dd9/1 and note that I'm trying to replace the names on the table before the filter occurs, not the search term itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**I have tested this on my copy of CodeIgniter and when formatted like this it works just fine:**

```
$items = $this->db->like("replace(name, '=', ' ')", "foo bar", 'both')->get('items')->num_rows();
```

**A few notes:**

1. You don't need from(), you can just slip the table into the get() method.
2. You can chain your methods so you only need to assign one variable.
3. Omitting the select() method implies select('*').

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax

```
$query = $this->db->select("*")->from('items')->like("replace(name, '=', ' ')", "foo bar", 'both')->get();
```

as shown [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) in fact is producing this query

```
SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE replace(name, '=', ' ') LIKE '%foo bar%';
```

If there is by accident one more space between foo and bar it fails.

Try this alternative query

```
SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE replace(name, '=', ' ') LIKE '%foo% bar%';
```

CodeIgniter

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')->from('items')->like("replace(name, '=', ' ')", "foo% bar", 'both')->get();
```

OR this query even better

```
SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE CONCAT(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '=', 1)),' ',TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '=', -1))) LIKE '%foo bar%';
```

Don't use this

```
SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE replace(name, '=', ' ') LIKE '%foo%bar%';
```

The results of those queries are shown [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e62ab/2)

Either you could have a query that removes leading/trailing space ([Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/58576))

Answer (score 2):

I cant find an method call `replace()` in associated with codeigniter or php.

Try `str_replace(find,replace,string)`

**Example**

```
$one = 'as = bb = cc=dd ';
$var = str_replace('=', ' ', $one);
echo $var;
```

[phpfiddle Preview](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ch7j-hpkw)

> > And don't refactor your code inside your query.  Make it clean and pass it to query. Its easy to track errors too.

Comment: `replace` method is available in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

I used

`$this->db->query()`

instead of

```
$this->db->select();
$this->db->order_by();
$this->db->get();
```

and it worked for me.

My query was:

```
$records = $this->db->select(
"id,( select count(*) from 
( select 
        unnest(string_to_array(mycol,',')) v
        from mytable ) t where v::int > 0) as total",
FALSE)->order_by("col1")->get("mytable1")->result_array();
```

Issue was, it was adding an extra space at `string_to_array(mycol,', ')` which was giving error.